# How to list and number text file contents in batch window and allow user selection?

Tags: android, batch-file

I am working on an android BAT file that will perform various functions.  One is that it will examine a folder on the phone ,list its contents, and save that list file local on my pc.  From there i want to take the file names and display them in the batch window and number them so the user can select a file name.

the following extracts the file names and saves them to text on my pc..

```
adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount /system"
adb shell su -c ls /system/app > apps.txt
adb shell su -c ls /system/framework > framework.txt
```

I can not figure out how to list these contents with numbers in the batch window for the user to make a selection.  The following will do what i want for files in a folder, but i want to do this for file "names" on a text document....

```
@ECHO OFF
SET index=1

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%f IN (*.*) DO (
   SET file!index!=%%f
   ECHO !index! - %%f
   SET /A index=!index!+1
)

SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET /P selection="select file by number:"

SET file%selection% >nul 2>&1

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   ECHO invalid number selected   
   EXIT /B 1
)

CALL :RESOLVE %%file%selection%%%

ECHO selected file name: %file_name%

GOTO :EOF

:RESOLVE
SET file_name=%1
GOTO :EOF
```

How do i perform this function on a list of names in a text file rather than a list of files in a folder?

Thanks,
Jimmie

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("my file.txt") do (
    set /a counter+=1
    call echo %%counter%% %%a
)
```

Comment: Great!...That does the trick but any selection I make says its invalid.  I am sure is has to do with the..."SET file%selection% >nul 2>&1" but im not sure how to fix it.